# postman is not rendering my HTML pages i write in express

Tags: node.js, express, npm, postman, ejs

im trying to link my HTML page with my express app and preview it through postman , but postman doesnt show my HTML content , i just get blank page , but when i just test using res.get("this is an example")it works perfectly fine and shows my text plus i have no errors in my code , anyone can help me identifying what the problem could be ? [in here i tried pretty tab and as you can see no preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftchu.jpg)

[and in here i tried preview tab and still nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efI75.jpg)

[visualize as well doesnt show any content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdY9Z.jpg)

and this is my code for the express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("server is listening!");
});
```

and i have a code as well in my home.ejs and this is it :

```
<h1>This is the home page</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured out the answer , its pretty stupid tbh but here is how i noticed it,
i went to the folder of views and saw that the home.ejs file is actually 0kb , so i opened it and its empty , so i pasted and saved and tried again its the same its still 0kb , so until i pasted the normal HTML code i attached above and i actually CLOSED the file from the editor tab thats when it saved and changed the size of the file to 1kb and i tested it and it worked perfectly fine as it should , so you have to close the ejs file from the editor after u write what you want .. really dumb issue if u ask me ..